# A function body must be provided. Try adding a function body

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

what's wrong
A function body must be provided.  Try adding a function body.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as _text_ rather then an image.

Comment: Did you try adding a function body?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `semiColon` i.e `;` after constructor or provide function body by adding `{}`

```
OnBoardingModel({
 required this.image,
 required this.title, 
 required this.body
});                     //  add this semicolon
```

or

```
OnBoardingModel({
 required this.image,
 required this.title, 
 required this.body
}){}                   //  add the function body this way
```